Error opening Jupyter notebook via Anaconda Navigator
When I try to open Jupyter it appears this message:
[W 2024-08-19 18:25:22.912 ServerApp] A `_jupyter_server_extension_points` function was not found in jupyter_lsp. Instead, a `_jupyter_server_extension_paths` function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[W 2024-08-19 18:25:23.012 ServerApp] A `_jupyter_server_extension_points` function was not found in notebook_shim. Instead, a `_jupyter_server_extension_paths` function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.107 ServerApp] Extension package panel.io.jupyter_server_extension took 1.0940s to import
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.129 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.135 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.141 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.146 ServerApp] notebook | extension was successfully linked.
[W 2024-08-19 18:25:24.540 ServerApp] A `_jupyter_server_extension_points` function was not found in jupyter_nbextensions_configurator. Instead, a `_jupyter_server_extension_paths` function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.540 ServerApp] jupyter_nbextensions_configurator | extension was found and enabled by notebook_shim. Consider moving the extension to Jupyter Server's extension paths.
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.540 ServerApp] jupyter_nbextensions_configurator | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.540 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.540 ServerApp] panel.io.jupyter_server_extension | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.582 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.584 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.584 ServerApp] [jupyter_nbextensions_configurator] enabled 0.6.4
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.584 ServerApp] jupyter_nbextensions_configurator | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.585 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.589 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.589 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.590 LabApp] Extension Manager is 'pypi'.
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.592 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.599 ServerApp] notebook | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.600 ServerApp] panel.io.jupyter_server_extension | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.601 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Henrique
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.601 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 2.14.1 is running at:
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.601 ServerApp] http://localhost:8888/tree?token=972cbd235a5cc3a6c3648fb897d5500c839132152a0a133a
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.601 ServerApp] http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree?token=972cbd235a5cc3a6c3648fb897d5500c839132152a0a133a
[I 2024-08-19 18:25:24.601 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[E 2024-08-19 18:25:24.601 ServerApp] Failed to write server-info to C:\Users\Henrique\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\jpserver-14092.json: PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
^^^^^^
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\application.py", line 623, in launch_instance
serverapp.start()
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 3119, in start
self.start_app()
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 3023, in start_app
self.write_browser_open_files()
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 2890, in write_browser_open_files
self.write_browser_open_file()
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 2913, in write_browser_open_file
with open(self.browser_open_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Henrique\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\jpserver-14092-open.html'

I did not try anything, because I don't know anything about programming and all of this stuff.

Does this answer help resolve your question?

I would recommend two possible fixes:

Run Anaconda Navigator or Jupyter as Administrator:Windows: Right-click on the Anaconda Navigator or Jupyter Notebook icon and choose "Run as administrator". This will give Jupyter the necessary permissions to write the required files.
Manually Set Permissions:Navigate to C:\Users\Henrique\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\ in File Explorer.Right-click on the runtime folder, select "Properties", then go to the "Security" tab.Ensure your user account has "Full control" permissions. If not, edit the permissions to allow full control.

